# How to change the add to cart button in WooCommerce with Book Now

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am working on a WooCommerce theme design & dynamic implementation, currently it has the add to cart option for its products (Normally it works as an e-commerce feature) in this project it has be different option product (it has 'Customised Plan' instead of 'Products') like when user visits to product description page user will select the plan with some options then instead of add to cart it should be Book Now button or something like that, the purpose is client will contact to the customer when the plan is booked & they'll charge them accordingly.
Please check the link of the live project:
https://demosoftwares.biz/Eat-Conscious/wp/product/ec-customized-plan/

Comment: Can you demonstrate any effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I've tried it & basically I am new to WooCommerce I didn't worked on it before, so I am searching any solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function change_default_add_to_cart_text($text) { 
    return __('Book Now', 'text-domain'); 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'change_default_add_to_cart_text' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'change_default_add_to_cart_text' );
```

Comment: Thanks @itzmekhokan its replaced the Book Now text